# Record video with external bluetooth mic (ie headset)

Tags: bluetooth, video-recording, bluetooth-audio

Can you record a video with the built-in camera while using a bluetooth audio source? Specifically, a standard bluetooth headset.

I know that you can record audio from the bluetooth headset using an app like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bluetooth.recorder&hl=en). And I just want to use the built-in camera.

I tried an experiment where I started recording audio using the [bluetooth recorder app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bluetooth.recorder&hl=en), then attemped to record a video. Unfortunately, the camcorder app refused to start a video recording. And I couldn't flip the order, because once I started recording the video, opening any other app (the bluetooth recorder, for example) caused the video recording to terminate. So it looks like I can't even record the two tracks separately and simultaneously to later splice together on a computer.

Does there exist an app that records video and lets the user choose the audio input? Is this even possible for android, or does the underlying kernel have a hardcoded audio input for video mode? I am a programmer, so if no app exists, I could try my hand at writing an android app if the system is capable.

Comment: This article describes a device that can do video recording with Bluetooth audio input. http://appledailyreport.com/2013/01/11/ces-nighthawk-bluetooth-microphone-combo-system-targeted-to-ios-android-devices/

Answer (score 10):

This app worked better for me:

[Cinema FV-5](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flavionet.android.cinema.lite&hl=en)

After installing the app, but before recording the video, do the following:

1. Click Settings
2. Click Audio Source
3. Select Bluetooth Mic

Then record your video.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, 
it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here 
and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes
Also, what is your affiliation with that app?

Comment: I have no affiliation with the app. It just worked for me.

Comment: This answer was better than Luca's. IGCamera had different microphone sources but none of them worked per the OG's specification. Also the different microphone sources were too many for the lay user to decipher. Cinema FV-5 was clear, concise and most importantly just worked. In addition, I have a stock At&t S5 Samsung. I walked away with my bluetooth headset and so long as I had good Line of Sight (LOS) to my phone it recorded my voice beautifully as I walked away from my phone. Great App!

Comment: Just now downloaded paid version cinemafv5. It works. Uploaded to Facebook to prove the point.
Free version did not work for me. Used Bluetooth Plantronics Explorer 50 Series.

Comment: @dwaynemac Cinema FV-5 is the best app. Only issue is you cannot record video with front camera in this app. Is it true, because I don't seem to find any option for that.?