# My android phone as a Bluetooth relay

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-audio, bluetooth-pairing

I'm a teacher. I use a portable personal amplifier in my class to make me louder. I was wondering whether it is possible to connect a Bluetooth mic and a Bluetooth speaker to an Android device and then redirect the input from the Bluetooth mic to the Bluetooth speaker. If it's possible, how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try them. Did it work for you ?

Comment: I'll test when I have time and I'll share the results

Comment: I started testing them today. I tested 3-4 apps. All of them had a considerable lag, which I thought was useless, then I stopped testing the rest.

Comment: Try this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.codococo.monomono) to connect to amplifier, it may work. It works for me in a [different context](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225178/131553)

Comment: @beeshyams No issues in establishing connection. The lag makes the use of the apps in the above answer impractical. That's the issue. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Surprised. I see no lag at all in recording videos. Are you sure you set it up right?

Comment: @beeshyams Nice! No I didn't try it. Let me try 

Comment: @beeshyams I tried this app- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=wimlog.com.myandroidtest4  to get audio from my phone's mic and to transmit it to bluetooth. I turned on bluetooth mono router and then used the app I've mentioned above. The lag is still present. I think getting audio and routing it to bluetooth introduces this lag. Thanks for you suggestion though

Comment: [Use Android device as BT speaker - see Victor's answer]( (https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5796/can-an-android-phone-be-used-as-a-bluetooth-headset-speakers)

Comment: @beeshyams thanks, will check it out!